# ORDER based on both own and other tables content - picking path optimization

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my mysql database:

shelfs

```
| shelf_name | product_name |
| ------------- | ------------ |
| 1             | Shampoo      |
| 2             | Conditioner  |
| 3             | Showergel    |
| 4             | Toothpaste   |
```

Each shelf_name represents a shelf.

lineitems

```
| order_name | product_name |
| ---------- | ------------ |
| Order1     | Shampoo      |
| Order1     | Conditioner  |
| Order2     | Toothpaste   |
| Order3     | Conditioner  |
| Order3     | Toothpaste   |
| Order4     | Showergel    |
```

Each line item represents an item in an order. An order can contain multiple items.

**Question:**

I want to get X order_names, but sorted in a way that the shelfs containing the items are as nearby as possible (or the orders are more similar).

For the tables above, probably the best order would be:
Order1
Order3
Order2
Order4

My first approach would be to go through order by order and then look for an order that has the same (or most similar) line items in it. Unfortunately this is not very accurate (if there are many different locations & products).

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: At a glance, trying to achieve this purely using MySQL query is not easy. Also I think your example is not covering all the possible scenarios... I mean, what if none of the product(s) in the next `OrderX` is the same or most similar or even not closely placed in the table `shelfs` to the previous one? Anyway, show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide expressions that determine "nearby" and "similar".